# Installing flooring in bathroom and new toilet

Tags: bathroom, flooring, toilet

new homeowner here that decided to take on too many projects while moving in!  One of our projects is installing new "peel-and-stick" laminate tiles from *Home Depot* and are 2mm thick.  We are planning on installing the tile on top of the existing linoleum flooring.  My question has to do with installing the toilet wax ring.  The current flange on the floor was installed on top of the linoleum flooring.

Will the additional 2mm on top of the existing floor warrant a taller wax ring?  Should we replace the flange in the floor and install the new one (the current one is busted, I bought a metal flange to put over it already) on top of the new flooring?  Just wondering what the proper procedure for this is.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your new flange one of the metal repair flanges that attaches to the old one? If so this will make up any difference in height. When I set a toilet I work the new wax into the ring on the toilet so it seals. When I place the toilet on the flange I check that the toilet has a space before pushing down as long as there is a small gap the wax ring will seal, if the toilet sits on the floor I pull the toilet up and add some wax I normally keep a very cheap wax ring no flange to add to a wax ring but vinyl usually is not thick enough to cause a problem

Comment: I ended up using a Hydroseat and the seal is great.  Only cost $20.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to replace the wax ring with a new one.  That way the toilet will form a new seal.  In fact it's a good idea to replace the wax ring any time you remove the toilet.

As far as your broken flange, obviously you will want to replace that.

Answer (score 0):

**If your flange was good**, the extra 2mm would make basically no difference with a standard new wax ring - they have a good range of compliance.

Since you have to **replace the flange**, do the floor and install it on top of the new floor.